# Solving Modular Equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $d$ and $n$ be coprime. What is the smallest positive solution for x in the equation:

$$d^x \equiv 1 \mod n$$

This value must depend on both $d$ and $n$. We know that the maximum value for it is $\lambda(n)$ where $\lambda$ is the Carmichael function, but the exact value can be smaller. The question can be alternatively phrased as:

Let $d$ and $n$ be coprime. What is the order of the group generated by $d$ under multiplication modulo $n$?

Comment: If you are expecting a simple answer, you are headed for a severe disappointment. There is a finite procedure for calculating the order, but there isn't any formula.

Comment: Indeed the disappointment was severe